# How to sort an array $A[1..n]$ with $\sqrt n$ distinct elements in $\Theta(n)$ time and $\Theta(\sqrt n)$ space?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, hash-tables

> I need to write an algorithm which will sort an array $A[1..n]$ with $\sqrt n$ distinct elements in $\Theta(n)$ time and $\Theta(\sqrt n)$ space?

The solution **must** use hash-tables and advanced data structures including any variation of trees is not allowed.

I thought of the following:

```
1 Sort(A, n)
2   init B[2][sqrt(n)] //B[1][sqrt(n)] will hold the distinct elements
                       //B[2][sqrt(n)] will hold the number of occurrences
                       //of element B[1][k] in the original array A
3   for i<-0 to n
4       hash(A[i]) //the hash function will also update B[2][i] counter
                   //of occurrences of A[i] in A
5   Quick-Sort(B[1][sqrt(n)]) //quick-sort will also move
                                  //B[2][k] when B[1][k] is moved
                                  //so that they're aligned
6   count<-0    //keeps track of the next location in A
7   for i<-0 to sqrt(n)
8       for j<-0 to B[2][i]
9           A[count]<-B[1][i] //copy the sorted array into the original array
10          count++
```

In terms of space complexity it looks right to me since we're using $\sqrt n$ additional space for the hash table.

In terms of time complexity I'm running into problems. The quick-sort operation (or according to my understanding any optimal sort for that matter) on line 5 takes $\Theta(\sqrt n \log{\sqrt n})=o(n)$ which is not $\Theta(n)$.

How can I modify the sorting part/algorithm in order to arrive to $\Theta(n)$ complexity?

Comment: I just realized that if the time complexities of other loops in the algorithm are $\Theta(n)$ and the sort is $o(n)$ then it's still $\Theta(n)$ in total. Am I right?

Comment: If you have an $o(n)$ algorithm and want to make it a $\Theta(n)$ algorithm, just add a loop running in time $\Theta(n)$. That said, any sorting algorithm runs in $\Omega(n)$, and indeed your algorithm already runs in time $\Theta(n)$. Moreover, it is pretty stupid to ask you to given an algorithm which performs *at least as bad* as $\Omega(n)$. Usually we are looking for fast algorithms rather than for slow ones.

Comment: Under **must** you mean it is given as task condition?

Comment: Yes it was given

Comment: @YuvalFilmus should I delete the post? I feel like I realized that the algorithm satisfies the conditions already as you mentioned

Comment: Perhaps someone else would find the discussion in the comments helpful.

Comment: Well, counting number of all distinct elements already takes $\Theta(n)$ time, so, I don't see problem. Thus, sorting your original array takes linear time.

Comment: @rus9384 yes you're right I realized that after I posted tbe question

Comment: I think Knuth covers this in TAoCP.